# Loop with upper bound of iterations / loop variant

Tags: gas-limit, out-of-gas, gas-estimate

Is it possible somehow to create a loop that solidity will recognize as having an upper bound of iterations for gas estimations?

Something like a loop variant in Eiffel (https://www.eiffel.org/doc/eiffel/ET-_Instructions#Loop_invariants_and_variants).

Currently I get infinite gas estimate whenever I have a for loop in my code.

Answer (score 0):

No, Solidity doesn't have such a thing built in. Is there a reason you care about the warning? You can just ignore it.

Comment: It'd be useful to get an actual gas estimate in such cases

Comment: For what purpose? I've never found the compiler-generated gas estimates to be useful; I just use estimates from real transactions instead.